# Docusign - How to scroll down to the end of document to enable a checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, docusignapi

I am using Docusign. I want a checkbox to be always on the bottom of the document. The checkbox is disabled before the user scrolls down the bottom. The checkbox is saying something like 'By clicking, I agree to the terms...". And once the checkbox is clicked and the Sign Tab is enabled.
Can I do this in the API? I have different types of documents, should I configure this in each of the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in the DocuSign API by using the `conditionalParentLabel` and `conditionalParentValue` mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Sign%20Here%20Tab.htm)

As an example, if I understand your question correctly, it would look like the structure below :
Create a checkbox, when it's checked by the user, it becomes "on" and the signature blocks gets enabled :

```
SignHere signBlock = new SignHere
{
    //Initialized the needed properties
    ConditionalParentLabel = "ConditionalCheckBox",
    ConditionalParentValue = "on"
};

Checkbox agreeingTerms = new Checkbox
{
    TabLabel = "ConditionalCheckBox"
};
```

Comment: Can we disable the checkbox unless user scoll down to the end of Document?

Comment: I don't think that the checkbox can be disabled on a user scroll condition, DocuSign doesn't seem to offer such a feature

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DocuSign templates to create an envelopes then you can configure the conditional fields as explained at [Conditional Fields](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-fields). If you are using API to create envelope without DS Templates then you can refer [DocuSign Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/signHere) to create conditional logic between checkbox and signhere tab.